# Does the Sony qx10 api support multiple simultaneous clients?

Tags: ios, sony-camera-api

Apologies in advance for the general-ness of the question.

I'm writing a multiple client iOS app for viewing the video feed from a single camera.  Can the QX10 api support two (or 3) iPad's discovering/viewing the same QX10 at the same time?

I've been looking QX10 sample code, the camera api docs, StackOverflow, and of course the dev website and haven't seen an answer.  I'd just buy the bloody thing to test with, but there are none nearby and I was hoping to avoid having to mail order/return it if it didn't work.

....And we're not locked into HW.  If there's a better option, I'm open....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it does.  For ios, the camera creates a network that the ios connects to. (In ios settings/wireless) Any further attempts to connect to the camera from another device fail.  Since the API only works after a network connection is established, I don't see how the API could possibly allow 2 devices could connect at once.

(No extraneous words in this post b/c that will get edited which auto down votes the question.....ahhh internet)

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it, but you could use a computer with nat. For example an openrwt router to open up multiple wifi interfaces, one to connect to the camera, using the 10.0.0.0 network the camera uses and then an other network to connect your clients with NAT. 
The question would be when the API would start to get confused.
So depending on what you want, maybe some mapper on that helper-computer could
do some proxying of information.

So in theory with an external box, maybe, but as Oldmicah said, it seems that only
one device can connect at the time (at least my QX100 also behaves like that). :(